# Generate 'source' column value when joining tables to form a view

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm creating an android app using sqlite and have the following question:

Is there any way I can generate a value for a 'source' column when joining two or more tables to create a view? For instance, Say I have the following two tables

```
Table 1 (Fruit)         Table 2 (Vegies)

Name   | Colour         Name    | Colour
-------|--------        --------|--------
Apple  | Red            Celery  | Green
Orange | Orange         Carrot  | Orange
Pear   | Green          Lettuce | Green
```

I'd like to create a view that looks something like this:

```
View (Food)

Name    | Colour  | Type
--------|---------|---------
Apple   | Red     | Fruit
Orange  | Orange  | Fruit
Pear    | Green   | Fruit
Celery  | Green   | Vegie
Carrot  | Orange  | Vegie
Lettuce | Green   | Vegie
```

This may or may not be possible... But I figured it would be worth asking. It is important that I can tell which table or 'source' the row came from in my application. There may be a better way to do it than with a view but I figured this way I can keep all of the data I get in their own tables (which have extra info specific to what the table holds) and I don't have to duplicate anything.

P.S. Very new to SQL/Sqlite so if you could add a bit of an explanation that would be awesome!

Many thanks.

Comment: You are asking for a UNION: see this [page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_unions_clause.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this would be a simple solution

```
select Fruits.*, 'Fruit' as type from Fruits union select Vegies.*, 
'Vegie' from vegies
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for this, it works great. A quick question though. How come you don't need to specifiy 'Vegie' as 'type' but it still puts it in that column?

Comment: It's standard sql syntax: the first query specifies data-types, whike queries added in "union" just have to maintain a "positional" convention, which means that fields at the same position must be of the same type

Comment: Ahh cool, so just to confirm... Say the two tables above had extra fields that were different to eachother, using Fruits.* and Vegies.* would no longer work, I'd have to manually state the columns that are present in both tables (i.e. name & colour)?

Comment: Exactly!! Just to point out, the two tables can have fields which differ by their names (e.g. Color and colour), and everything will work fine if the types is the same of the two columns (string). The resulting table will have a field whose name is the name of the field used in the first of the two queries appearing in the union

Comment: You're a legend mate. Thanks so much for your help!